# testing a vriable scoped whose scope is inside a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am unit testing my ionic app with `Jasmine`. I have a service function to handle file upload.

```
  fileUpload(filePath: string,apiEndpoint: string){
    const fileTransfer = new Transfer();
    let fileName = filePath.substr(filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    let options = Object.assign( this.httpHeader(),{chunkedMode: false, fileName: fileName});
    return fileTransfer.upload(filePath, apiEndpoint, options)
    .then((data) => {
      return data;
    }).catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

The scope of `fileTransfer` is inside the function, so it is not available in the test.`fileTransfer.upload` call would fail inside the function as it is a `cordova` library.

```
  it('updateImage updates the image of user',(done)=>{
    auth.fileUpload("path","url").then((data)=>{
      done();
    })
  })
```

One possible solution which I can think of is `this.fileTransfer = new Transfer();` . Is there any other way to mock the library or intercept it?

Answer (score 0):

I've written this without running it, but something along these lines may be the start of what you need;

```
describe('updateImage', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        spyOn(window, 'Transfer').and.returnValue({
            upload: jasmine.createSpy('fileTransfer.upload').and.returnValue(
                Promise.resolve({
                    the: 'data that fileTransfer.upload returns'
                })
            )
        });
    });
    afterEach(() => {
        window.Transfer.reset();
    });
    it('updateImage updates the image of user', done => {
        auth.fileUpload("path", "url").then(data => done());
    });
});
```

Comment: I get this error  ``Error: <spyOn> : Transfer() method does not exist ``

Comment: Where do you locate `Transfer` from? Not a global?

Comment: I have it in my service which I am testing. `` import {  Transfer   } from 'ionic-native'; ``

Comment: Something like https://github.com/speedskater/babel-plugin-rewire will let you substitute imports for fake versions in your tests.